# Field has disappeared on post page

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have taken over a site from someone.
He has a list of businesses on the site, each one has a URL, saved as a field:

`$iframe_url = get_field(‘manufacturer_url’);`

It seems he used to manage this URL on a custom post-type page, but the actual field to edit the URL has disappeared – maybe in some recent WordPress update.

I have made sure on the edit page, all the elements are checked off on the ‘screen options’ tab. But i still cannot see where this field is, where i can change the URL. Any ideas?

Using Version 5.8.7 of the plugin
WP version: WordPress 5.1.4 running Chameleon-Child theme.

Comment: Are you using the Block Editor? Some old meta fields need to be explicitly set to show in the REST API so they work with the new Editor.

Comment: @WebElaine - yes, I'm using the block editor. Can you explain what should be done?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followup for any future questioner.

It seems like the Field Group of ACF had been deleted. As soon as i created a new group and field named `'manufacturer_url'` the fields all became accessible again.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To expose a postmeta field in the Block Editor, you need to register it and enable it to show in the REST API.

With your field being named "manufacturer_url" you would use something like this:

```
<?php
// Use "init" hook
add_action('init', 'wpse_register_mfr_postmeta');
function wpse_register_mfr_postmeta() {
    // Make sure to set your CPT slug as the first argument
    register_post_meta('mycptslug', 'manufacturer_url', array(
        // Critical part: show in REST API
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        // You're probably storing a string but double-check first:
        'type' => 'string',
        // If you only allow 1 manufacturer_url per post, use this
        'single' => true
    ));
}
?>
```

You can place this in a custom or child theme's "functions.php" file, or as its own custom plugin just by adding a comment with "Plugin Name" at the top. (Since you probably don't want the data disappearing if you switch themes, setting it up as a plugin is likely the best approach.)

Comment: Thank you. Done this (as a plugin) but I don't see the field appear anywhere.

Comment: Check through the codebase to make sure you also have code to add the actual metabox and save its data. If that is missing, you'll need to rebuild it. There are some additional meta troubleshooting tips in the Block Editor Handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/backward-compatibility/meta-box/